# User Identification in React Native with sim card

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and it's important to check if the user who is logged in has the same phone number as the sim card on that phone.
Is there any good way to do that?

Comment: number checking impossible. there might be sim unique number will be there.

Comment: https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure you'll always get a phone number on mobile platforms.
There are no way to do it in 100% cases for all devices